# Lead-acid batteries discharged too far

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid, over-discharge

I have been working with two 12 V lead-acid batteries in series. Accidently, we kept them turned on for a day or two and one of them drained to ~3 V and the other to ~8 V.

I immediately charged them, but they get charged and drained super quickly. I read about recovery charge on this forum, but my charger doesn't seem to have a recovery charge function.

Also, sometimes it gets charged to 16 V on balance charge. Can those batteries be recovered or should I replace them?

Comment: Do you mean "lead acid"? They fail rapidly when heavily discharged, and most likely now need to be replaced.

Comment: Lead acetate you say? Perhaps you could turn them into solar cells https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2211285519310948

Comment: Sorry for mistake I meant lead acid battery

Comment: Depends. If you charge them up, preferably to 16 V, let them bubble a little and refill any lost water (distilled), they may very well be serviceable. Do you have access to any ESR or load tester?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to recover it. That battery went dead. Used it for other minor application and bought new battery for my original application.